# Draw y-axis inside the graph area with chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using chart.js I want to draw the y-axis inside the graph area.

So instead of being left (or right) to the canvas area with the graphs the y-axis values should be drawn inside like this:

[image: Graph with y-axsis inside]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could accomplish that, by setting the [**`mirror`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration) property to **`true`** for y-axis ticks.

```
options: {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            mirror: true
         }
      }]
   },
   ...
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Statistics',
         data: [30, 10, 20, 50, 40],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.1)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.8)',
         tension: 0
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               mirror: true //<-- set this
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Together with the `padding` property I could achieve the exact effect that I needed. Thank you!